# Compound validation rules without extending the Compound constraint with Symfony Validator

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

I'm using the validator component as a standalone package for data validations.

I have a class that contains methods that return common validation cases, like this one:

```php
    public function selectOneFrom(array $choices): Constraint
    {
        return new RequireAll([
            new Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint\NotNull(),
            new Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint\Choice($choices),
        ]);
    }
```

As far as I can tell, the only option to return a compound rule is to return it as an `array`. What I am after is not having a `: Constraint|array` return value type hint on these methods that return compound rules.

What I do not understand is why there is no concrete `Compound` constraint. Here, I created my own `RequireAll`, which extends the Compound and is pretty trivial:

```
class RequireAll extends Compound
{
    public function __construct(iterable $constraints, $options = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($options);
        $this->constraints = is_array($constraints) ? $constraints : iterator_to_array($constraints);
    }

    protected function getConstraints(array $options): array
    {
        return $this->constraints;
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

P.S.: I know I'm supposed to extend the `Compound` class, but this way I can parametrize the rules with less effort than creating a new class for each compound validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I'm supposed to extend the Compound class, but this way I can parametrize the rules with less effort than creating a new class for each compound validation rule.

Is it really less effort, though?

```php
class SelectOneFrom extends Compound
{
    public array $choices;

    protected function getConstraints(array $options): array
    {
        return [
            new Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint\NotNull(),
            new Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint\Choice($options['choices']),
        ];
    }

    public function getRequiredOptions()
    {
        return ['choices'];
    }

    public function getDefaultOption()
    {
        return 'choices';
    }
}
```

It is more code, if you are counting lines, but its still quite simple.  Prior to the `Compound` constraint, it was far more difficult to create the equivalent `SelectOneFrom` constraint.

The benefit of having a `SelectOneFrom` constraint is that it is far more portable than having to depend on a call to the `::selectOneFrom` factory method. *(I.e. if you use XML or Attributes for setting constraints on object properties.)*

---

The alternative is to neither define `SelectOneFrom` nor `RequireAll` constraints and just have your factory method return an array.

```php
    /**
     * @return Constraint[]
     */
    public function selectOneFrom(array $choices): array
    {
        [
            new Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint\NotNull(),
            new Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint\Choice($choices),
        ];
    }
```

If its adequate for your project to call a factory method, then having it return an array of constraints is equal to it returning a single `RequireAll` constraint.

Comment: The real question is, why is something like `RequireAll` not a part of Symfony validation package? I may just be missing something. What I am after is returning `Constraint` type only, not arrays nor `Constraint|array`, for consistency purposes.